# About a proof of the minimal polynomial of matrix doesn't change when the field changed

Tags: linear-algebra

In Keith. Conrad's lecture notes, he proved the following theorem

**Theorem**:
  Let $K/F$ be any field extension.

(1) For any $A\in\operatorname{M}_n(F)$, its minimal polynomial in $F[x]$ is its minimal polynomial in $K[x]$.

(2) Two matrices in $\operatorname{M}_n(F)$ are conjugate in $\operatorname{M}_n(F)$ if and only if they are conjugate in $\operatorname{M}_n(F)$.

The following is his proof of (1):

Let $m(x)$ be the minimal polynomial of $A$ in $F[x]$. Since $m(x)\in K[x]$ and $m(A)=O$, $m(x)$
  is divisible by the minimal polynomial of $A$ in $K[x]$. Next we show that if $f(x)\in K[x]$ and $f(A)=O$ then there exists a polynomial in $F[x]$ of the same degree which kills $A$, so $\deg f\geq m(x)$. Therefore, $m(x)$ is the minimal polynomial of $A$ in $K[x]$.

Suppose
  $$A^r+a_{r-1}A^{r-1}+\cdots+a_1A+a_0I=O,$$
  where $a_i\in K$. Consider $A^{i}$ as an $F^{nn}$ vector, then $\{A^r,A^{r-1},\dots,A,I\}$ are linearly dependent or the equation
  $$[I,A,\dots,A^{r-1}]\begin{bmatrix}
    x_1\\
    x_2\\
    \vdots\\
    x_{r}
  \end{bmatrix}=A^r$$
  has a nonzero solution in $K^r$, hence it has a nonzero solution in $F^r$. Therefore, there exists $b_0,\dots,b_{r-1}\in F$ not all zero, such that
 $$A^r+b_{r-1}A^{r-1}+\cdots+b_1A+b_0I=O.$$

**My question is: Is the following proof correct?:**

Let $m_F(x)$ be the minimal polynomial of $A$ in $F[x]$ and $m_K(x)$ the minimal polynomial of $A$ in $K[x]$. Then we have
    $F[A]\simeq F[x]/(m_F(x))$ and $K[A]=K[x]/(m_K(x))$. Since
  $$K[A]=K\otimes_F F[A]=K\otimes_F F[x]/(m_F(x))=K[x]/(m_F(x))$$. 
We deduce that 
$$m_F(x)=m_K(x)$$.
  But we know that the minimal polynomial of $\sqrt{2}$ over $\Bbb{Q}$ is $x^2-2$ and 
  over $\Bbb{R}$ is $x-\sqrt{2}$. We see that
  $$\Bbb{Q}[\sqrt{2}]\simeq\Bbb{Q}[x]/(x^2-2)$$
  and
  $$\Bbb{R}[\sqrt{2}]=\Bbb{R}\neq\Bbb{R}\otimes\Bbb{Q}[x]/(x^2-2)=\Bbb{R}[x]/(x^2-2).$$
Could anyone explain the difference for me?

Comment: $\Bbb{R}[\sqrt{2}]=\Bbb{R}$ is a field but $\Bbb{R}\otimes\Bbb{Q}[\sqrt{2}]$ is not a field.

Comment: The tensor product of two fields need not be a field again - see http://mathoverflow.net/questions/82083/when-is-the-tensor-product-of-two-fields-a-field.

Comment: I know this, i just don't know whether the second proof is correct. Is it a proof. So I give the example. I need someone to explain the difference of them.

Comment: What difference do you mean ?

Comment: First, is the second proof about the minimal polynomial of matrix correct. I am not sure. Amitai Yuval give an expleination below. He/She just give an example which partially answer my doubt. What is the difference between number and vector, the difference of number(fields) and vector space(Maybe). My english is not good, make sure you understand what I say.

Comment: @ Dietrich Burde. Are you availiable? Amitai Yuval give an example which pick $a\in K\backslash F$. But in my question, the matrix $A\in\operatorname{M}_n(F)$. I think $K[A]=K\otimes_F F[A]=K\otimes_F F[x]/(m_F(x))=K[x]/(m_F(x))$ is always right when $A$ is a matrix(The Conrad's proof). Is my understanding is right? So the question is coming, the difference between vector and the field. My poor english. I can't express my viewpoint very well.

Answer (score 2):

In general, it is *not* true that $$K[a]=K\otimes_FF[a].$$ For example, take $K$ to be a finite extension of F, and take $a\in K\setminus F$. The LHS is then just $K$. The RHS is the tensor product of two vector spaces over $F$, so it is a again a vector space, whose dimension is equal to the product of dimensions of $K$ and $F[a]$ respectively. Since $a\not\in F$, this product is greater than the dimension of $K$ over $F$.

This explains what happens in the example with $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$ and $\mathbb{R}$.

However, when working with matrices, the above equation does hold if one defines everything properly, as the following.

First we define $i:F\hookrightarrow M_n(F)$ by mapping every $x\in F$ to $xI$, and denote by $F'$ the image of $i$. $F'$ is clearly a field, isomorphic to $F$. Then, given a matrix $A\in M_n(F)$ with minimal polynomial $m_F(x)$, it is true that $$F'[A]\cong F'[x]/m'_F(x)\cong F[x]/m_F(x),$$where $m'_F(x)$ is the image of $m_F(x)$ under the obvious extension of $i$. If we identify every $x\in K$ with the matrix $xI$, and call the image $K'$, it is then true that $$K'[A]\cong K'\otimes_{F'}F'[A],$$and all the following statements in the posted proof are also true, thus the proof for equality of minimal polynomials is valid.

Comment: So the second proof about the minimal polynomial doesn't change when the base field changed is wrong?

Comment: This $a\in K\backslash F$ can be viewed as a vector over $F$?(of course) So the formula $K[A]=K\otimes F[A]$ is wrong in general?

Comment: I'm afraid so (this refers to both your comments).

Comment: As I pointed to  Dietrich Burde, in your example, you pick $a\in K\backslash F$ . But in my question, the matrix $A\in\operatorname{M}_n(F)$. I feel the formula $K[A]=K\otimes_F F[A]=K\otimes_F F[x]/(m_F(x))=K[x]/(m_F(x))$ is always right when A  is a matrix(The Conrad's proof), even when $n=1$. Could you explain it more?

Comment: @HGF I think you're right. Have a look at the edited answer.

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanation. I need time to digest it. I just wondering why there are so many difference between fields and vector space(the structure. As your first respondence, the tensor product)